# iPhone 5 Optimisation

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm super confused about how the iPhone 4 and below apps are optimised for the iPhone 5. I'm a designer. How is optimisation done? Basically I have an app with loads of knobs and buttons and other interactive components. The way I see it, there are 3 options but what is the best way (or least, standard practice)?

1) Keep the layout the same for iPhone 5 but just add extra length on the background.

2) Scale the images/layout of components from iPhone 4 to iPhone 5 so everything is proportional.

3) Have completely separate images and different layouts for both. i.e for iPhone 5, I can move components to utilise the space more. The problem with this (and I'm not a developer) is that the interaction position of the components have moved so in effect, the iPhone 4 and 5 are separate apps?

Comment: Are we talking UIKit?

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys. Option 3, is that even an option?

Comment: There are plenty of good Answers Here. Don't you think , you should Accept One of them.

Answer (score 1):

To identify if it is a iphone 5 iphone, use this code in the file `nameYourApp-prefix.pch`:

```
//Macro iPhone5
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

find the `nameYourApp-prefix.pch` file in the supporting files, the code must be written between:

```
# ifdef __ OBJC__

      //Code Macro iPhone5

# endif
```

and then just use the "if" to check that device, like this:

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {

    //Code for 4 inch screen

}else{

   //Code for 3.5 inch screen

}
```

putting the macro in the `nameYourApp-prefix.pch`, all classes see it.

Answer (score 1):

With a **UIKit application**, none of your options are ideal. You simply use Springs and Struts or Auto Layout to have your user interface elements snap to where they should be.

The solution is the same when switching between portrait and landscape orientation. You define which user interface elements can grow and which ones can't, which edges to snap to, etc.

Run it on the simulator to test the layout if you don't have an iPhone 5 device.

For example, for a `UITableViewController`, the `UITableView` should grow vertically on an iPhone 5 so that you see more rows.

I almost always have at least one control that would be nice to grow given the room. If you don't, then you'll probably just have more empty space at the bottom of the view.

Comment: I'm not a developer but are you saying that Spring/Struts/Auto Layout will automatically position the elements to an appropriate place regardless of the size of the screen?

Comment: @user2270622, Yes. You simply set it up to allow one of the controls to grow.

Answer (score 0):

### How iPhone 5 Optimization Works

When you tell iOS that your app is optimized for the iPhone 5 (through use of a cleverly named image file), iOS uses your existing Springs and Struts or Auto Layout (whatever you're using) to rearrange the interface.

Comment: Does Springs/Struts/Auto Layout work if the images of the button is in a slightly different location on the iPhone 4 compared to the iPhone 5?

Answer (score 0):

**The first choice** is the easiest and works pretty well. You'd only need to worry about having specific assets for full screen images, and make sure that NavigationBar and TabBar (in case your app have one), remains on top and bottom respectively.

Scaling other images/components such as buttons, you'll change the general aspect ratio (which you probably wouldn't want), since iPhone 4&5 display sizes only differ in height.

Comment: Yeah, Id rather not change the aspect ratio. Is option 3 even an option?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it at all, as you will need to do any change/fix twice. You can use the same layout for both iPhone 4 and 5, and use `Autosizing` tool in your xib views to fix some views to top/down, and to automatically "expand" the main content views (such us main scroll/table)

Answer (score 0):

For developing app option two is better. Although you dont have to change all the images for iPhone 5 some images will me same like TabBarItem. But you have to create background image different for iPhone4 and 5.

Read out this [apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1) to create user interface.

And you can differentiate iPhone 4 from iPhone 5 using this code

```
    UIBtton * btn = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

            if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
            {
              btn.frame = CGRectMake(60,60, 205, 175); 
              //this is for iPhone5
            }
            else
            {
              btn.frame = CGRectMake(60,50, 199, 170); 
              //this is for iPhone4
            }
```

Here my button place and length are different for iPhone 5 and iPhone 4

And set your control's hight and width according to iPhone Screen Size.

Comment: But how does that solve space? Say if I had multiple buttons for iPhone 4 but then go to iphone 5, the buttons will be clumped together. So the way to solve this is to move the buttons (i.e option 3)?

Comment: As i said you have to specify your control's X,Y,Width,Hight value in code that i showed according to screen so your control will not be overlapped. check my answer now i have added sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't, adjust your **view layouts with proper auto resizing masks** or look into **Auto Layout** if you only want to support iOS 6 going forward. You have to check height of `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`.

**Example:**

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    // code for 4-inch screen (iPhone 5)
} else {
    // code for 3.5-inch screen (< iPhone 5)
}
```

Note that `[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]` will only load either "background.png" or **"yourImage@2x.png"**, it will not load **"yourImage-568h@2x.png"** if it exists.

Check **Auto-Rotation API** as Well.

Comment: Does Auto Layout work if the images of the button is in a slightly different location on the iPhone 4 compared to the iPhone 5?